yt-dlp Error: 'Sign in required' When Downloading YouTube Video
I'm trying to download audio from a YouTube Shorts video using yt-dlp, but I keep encountering an error that says "Sign in to confirm you’re not a bot." I would like to know how to resolve this issue to successfully download the audio.
Command Used
Here is the command I executed in my terminal:
yt-dlp --user-agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.3" -f bestaudio -o "output.mp3" "https://youtube.com/shorts/V7YCOMkQtMI?si=otM-DOvIV7ZZas4N"



ERROR: [youtube] V7YCOMkQtMI: Sign in to confirm you’re not a bot. This helps protect our community.


const downloadAudio = async (url, outputFilePath) => {
    console.log('Attempting to download audio from URL:', url); // Log the URL

    const ytDlpCommand = [
        'yt-dlp',
        
        '--user-agent',
        '"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.3"',
        '-f', 'bestaudio',
        '-o', outputFilePath,
        '--restrict-filenames',
        '--no-mtime',
        '-v', 
        url 
    ];


    const commandString = ytDlpCommand.join(' ');

    try {
        console.log('Executing command:', commandString); // Log the command being executed
        const { stdout, stderr } = await execPromise(commandString); //

        // Log stdout and stderr for debugging
        console.log('yt-dlp stdout:', stdout);
        if (stderr) {
            console.error('yt-dlp stderr:', stderr); 
            throw new Error(`yt-dlp stderr output indicates a problem: ${stderr}`);
        }

        return stdout; // Return the standard output
    } catch (error) {
     
        console.error('Error in downloadAudio:', error.message);
        console.error('Full command executed:', commandString); 
        throw new Error('Failed to download audio'); 
    }
};


Tried different URLs: I tested multiple YouTube videos, including regular and Short videos, but the error persists.
Changed User Agent: I used a different user agent string but still received the same error.
Checked Network and Proxy Settings: I ensured that my network connection was stable and that no proxies were interfering with the request.
Tested on Another Device: I attempted to download the same video on a different device where yt-dlp is also installed, but I encountered the same error

on my personal laptop, yt-dlp works out of the box. on my oracle vps, same login request issue you’ve experienced. seems to be a lot of reports online of data centre IP’s experiencing this issue in recent months, following a youtube crackdown on bots.
taking browser cookies has been suggested as a solution and also marked as “absolutely do not do” as it will flag your account… i can’t attest to this either way.
but i did successfully solve the issue by using this oauth plugin. it may be prudent to recommend using a second account, not your main account, given the warnings on the cookie solution.
https://github.com/coletdjnz/yt-dlp-youtube-oauth2
EDIT: as it apparently wasn't clear, this solves the issue by signing you in to yt-dlp as the error message suggests you need to do

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
